# Mobile responsive bootstrap media queries

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 HTML, CSS & JavaScript

I am having trouble making mobile devices smaller than the stated sm-device media query render the appropriate styling?

```
@media (max-width: 575px) { do something..}
```

It keeps selecting the medium media query instead and renders a view that is meant for larger devices!

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { do something else..}
```

Comment: Show the actual `do something else..`. Are the CSS selectors specific enough?

Comment: The content of the media queries are font size, padding and margin changes.. They work, the issue is that the mobile version (max-width: 575px) is not being selected? The mobile view for some reason is the (max-width: 767px)

Comment: We need a snippet or a live example. I don't think anyone is going to be able to help you by reading the description.

Comment: I have added screenshots on whats happening

Comment: I fixed it with @media (max-width: 767px ) and (min-width: 576px) { do something else..}

Comment: If you are using Media queires with bootstrap I have to question your use of Bootstrap. There is a xs option to be used for extra small screens. Smaller than the sm you mention